# How can I improve the performance of this sql query?

Tags: sql, db2

My table has 51 million rows of data, comprised of 500k products.  I need to pull information on the 500k products like the attached code, but currently this takes more than 30 minutes to run.

Tried several different iterations, but can only see good performance which limiting product list in each sub-select, and main select

Snippet of table:

```
PNUM | EFFECTIVE_DATE | STAGE | ORG_ID | CURRENT_FLAG
-- | -- | -- | -- | --
2A1245 | 1999-10-01 | 07 | W6 | N
2A1245 | 2006-01-01 | 07 | U4 | N
2A1245 | 2007-11-21 | 07 | U4 | N
2A1245 | 2008-03-23 | 07 | KF | N
2A1245 | 2008-11-23 | 07 | KF | N
2A1245 | 2009-02-25 | 07 | KF | N
2A1245 | 2015-03-19 | 07 | U5 | N
2A1245 | 2015-04-14 | 07 | U6 | N
2A1245 | 2015-04-17 | 07 | U6 | N
2A1245 | 2015-05-01 | 07 | U6 | N
2A1245 | 2017-09-26 | 08 | 8X | N
2A1245 | 2019-02-20 | 08 | 8X | N
2A1245 | 2019-03-18 | 08 | 8X | N
2A1245 | 2019-04-24 | 08 | 8X | N
2A1245 | 2019-04-29 | 08 | 8X | N
2A1245 | 2019-05-11 | 08 | 8X | N
2A1245 | 2019-05-15 | 08 | 8X | N
2A1245 | 2019-06-05 | 08 | 1Z | N
2A1245 | 2019-06-08 | 09 | W1E | N
2A1245 | 2019-06-11 | 09 | W1E | N
2A1245 | 2019-08-19 | 09 | EBI | N
2A1245 | 2019-09-03 | 09 | EBI | Y
```

```
SELECT a.PNUM, c.STAGE, MIN(a.EFFECTIVE_DATE) AS NEW_DATE, c.STAGE_CHANGE
FROM D_PRODUCT a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT x.PNUM, x.STAGE FROM D_PRODUCT x 
            WHERE CURRENT_FLAG = 'Y' ) b ON b.PNUM = a.PNUM
LEFT JOIN (SELECT y.PNUM, y.STAGE, MIN(y.EFFECTIVE_DATE) AS STAGE_CHANGE 
          FROM D_PRODUCT y    GROUP BY y.PNUM, y.STAGE) c 
            ON b.PNUM= c.PNUM AND b.STAGE = C.STAGE
  GROUP BY a.PNUM, c.STAGE, c.STAGE_CHANGE
```

OUTPUT:

```
PNUM   | STAGE | NEW_DATE   | STAGE_CHANGE
--     | --    | --         | --
2A1245 | 09    | 1999-10-01 | 2019-06-08
```

Currently takes a few seconds to run with limiting to single product or PNUM within each sub-select, and main select, but times out after 30 minutes or so when not limited

Comment: What are the semantics of that query? Does the data fit in memory or is on disk? What indexes are used and what does the explain output say (query plan)?

Comment: I am afraid I don't know what you mean by semantics of the query.  The current testing is being done with DBVisualizer, so assume the output is memory.  there are  Indexes: +PNUM, +PNUM+EFFECTIVE_DATE, +CURRENT_FLAG, +PNUM+CURRENT_FLAG.  The output looks like this: PNUM | STAGE | HIRE_DATE | STAGE_CHANGE
-- | -- | -- | --
2A1245 | 09 | 1999-10-01 | 2019-06-08

Comment: What is the query plan (explain)? With semantics I mean something like "I want to return only products with effective date of ... and being in stage x with ..."

Comment: I want to return all products with 1 row of data.  pnum, Stage when current_flag = Y, MIN(Effective_DATE) overall, and MIN(effective_date) when stage is = stage when current_flag is Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following SQL.

```
select b.pnum, max(current_stage) current_stage, 
min(b.effective_date) as new_date,
max(case when b.current_stage = b.stage then b.effective_date else null end) as STAGE_CHANGE
from
(select a.pnum , a.stage , 
min(a.effective_date) as effective_date, 
max(case when a.current_flag = 'Y' then a.stage else null end) as current_stage
from  D_PRODUCT a
group by a.pnum , a.stage) b
group by b.pnum
```

Comment: Thank you!  The above reduced the more than 30 minute query to only 10 minutes.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no need to join table thrice. This can be achieved with 2 joins also and that might increase the performance -

```
SELECT a.PNUM, c.STAGE, a.EFFECTIVE_DATE, c.STAGE_CHANGE
FROM D_PRODUCT a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT y.PNUM, y.STAGE, MIN(y.EFFECTIVE_DATE) AS STAGE_CHANGE 
           FROM D_PRODUCT y
           GROUP BY y.PNUM, y.STAGE) c ON a.PNUM= c.PNUM AND a.STAGE = c.STAGE
```

After this you may have the composit index on `(PNUM, STAGE)`

Answer (score 0):

Using a co-related sub-selects might help your performance.

```
WITH D_PRODUCT ( PNUM , EFFECTIVE_DATE , STAGE , ORG_ID , CURRENT_FLAG ) AS (VALUES 
 ('2A1245' , '1999-10-01' , 07 , 'W6' , 'N')
,('2A1245' , '2006-01-01' , 07 , 'U4' , 'N')
,('2A1245' , '2007-11-21' , 07 , 'U4' , 'N')
,('2A1245' , '2008-03-23' , 07 , 'KF' , 'N')
,('2A1245' , '2008-11-23' , 07 , 'KF' , 'N')
,('2A1245' , '2009-02-25' , 07 , 'KF' , 'N')
,('2A1245' , '2015-03-19' , 07 , 'U5' , 'N')
,('2A1245' , '2015-04-14' , 07 , 'U6' , 'N')
,('2A1245' , '2015-04-17' , 07 , 'U6' , 'N')
,('2A1245' , '2015-05-01' , 07 , 'U6' , 'N')
,('2A1245' , '2017-09-26' , 08 , '8X' , 'N')
,('2A1245' , '2019-02-20' , 08 , '8X' , 'N')
,('2A1245' , '2019-03-18' , 08 , '8X' , 'N')
,('2A1245' , '2019-04-24' , 08 , '8X' , 'N')
,('2A1245' , '2019-04-29' , 08 , '8X' , 'N')
,('2A1245' , '2019-05-11' , 08 , '8X' , 'N')
,('2A1245' , '2019-05-15' , 08 , '8X' , 'N')
,('2A1245' , '2019-06-05' , 08 , '1Z' , 'N')
,('2A1245' , '2019-06-08' , 09 , 'W1E' , 'N')
,('2A1245' , '2019-06-11' , 09 , 'W1E' , 'N')
,('2A1245' , '2019-08-19' , 09 , 'EBI' , 'N')
,('2A1245' , '2019-09-03' , 09 , 'EBI' , 'Y')
)

SELECT
    PNUM
,   STAGE
,   (SELECT MIN(EFFECTIVE_DATE) FROM D_PRODUCT M WHERE m.PNUM = a.PNUM) AS EFFECTIVE_DATE
,   (SELECT MIN(EFFECTIVE_DATE) FROM D_PRODUCT C WHERE c.PNUM = a.PNUM AND c.STAGE = a.STAGE ) AS STAGE_CHANGE
FROM D_PRODUCT a
WHERE 
    CURRENT_FLAG = 'Y'
```

Returns

```
PNUM      STAGE   EFFECTIVE_DATE  STAGE_CHANGE
------    -----   --------------  ------------
2A1245    9       1999-10-01      2019-06-08
```